# Different buddy lists for different accounts in iChat

Tags: macos, ichat

I have currently 4 accounts added to iChat,

1. Standard GTalk
2. GTalk For Google Apps
3. Facebook
4. Olark

Facebook and Olark have their own Buddy List Group viz. `Facebook` and `WebUser` groups and thus those buddies come in a separate list, while the buddies from GTalk and GTalk from Google Apps do not have any group associated with them and they come under `Buddies` list.

It's a bit of a pain because I want to have buddies from GTalk for Google Apps in a separate buddy list than the default one.

Is it possible to do it in iChat?

Answer (score 2):

In your preferences, disable one of the Google accounts.

Then, right click on the 'Buddies' divider and rename it to anything else. Finally, re-enable the account you disabled and you will achieve the desired separation.

Answer (score 1):

Turning off *Preferences → General → Show all my accounts in one list* will give you four separate buddy list windows. I don't know of a way to specify an alternate group for a single account.